# Abelian group $A$ of order $N^r$ such that ${\rm Card}(A[D]) = D^r$ for all $D\mid N$. Show $A$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/{N\mathbb{Z}})^r$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $A$ be an abelian group of order $N^r$ such that ${\rm Card}(A[D]) = D^r$ for all divisor $D$ of $N$.

Here $A[D]$ is the subgroup of elements $a$ such that $D\cdot a = 0$.

I need to show that under those conditions $A$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/{N\mathbb{Z}})^r$.

I can show that if the group has cardinal $p^r$ ($p$ prime) then it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/{p\mathbb{Z}})^r$ because every non-zero element has order $p$. I don't know where to go from that.

Would you have a proof in simple terms, relying only on basic group theory results if possible?

*Note: I found this problem in [Arithmetic of elliptic curves](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-09494-6), which is way above my level but for some reasons I'd like to be able to understand the structure of $E[n]$ on an elliptic curve $E$ (I'm interested in applications of elliptic curves to cryptography but I have very limited knowledge of group theory).*

Comment: I'd consider induction on the number of primes factors of $N$.  You might also consider the quotient group under the homomorphism $\varphi:A \to A$ defined by $\varphi(a)=d \cdot a$ to help with the inductive step.

Comment: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Finite_abelian_groups

Comment: @Shaun it's actually an exercise from a book on elliptic curves. The goal is to show that (under some conditions) the group $E[n]$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$.

I can show that if a group has cardinal $p^r$ then it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^r$ because every non-zero element has order $p$. I don't know where to go from that.

Comment: Thank you, @Weier. Please [edit] your question with those details. This would constitute necessary context. Not everyone checks the comments. Also, please tell us which book you're referring to.

Comment: Also, what is $n$?

Comment: There is no $n$ in the original problem formulation (at least now that I fixed it), only $N$ which is a positive integer such that $A$ has order $N^r$.

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups? I'd start there to see if I could adapt parts of its proof . . .

Comment: Yes, see the link in my comment above. And you don't need to adapt the proof. You can use the theorem as a blackbox.